# Many-to-many and one-to-many relationships with same types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have an internal messaging application project. The business requirements require two types of addresses, plain text addresses or address codes which are just shorthand used for addresses. You may think it like a radio operator name but not so cryptic.

Also, EF Core requires join classes for many-to-many classes. Therefore, the address relationship gets complicated.

Here's a sample `Message` class. You can see that `Info` is nullable.

```
#nullable
public class Message
{
    public MessageAddress From { get; set; }
    public List<MessageAddress> To { get; set; }
    public List<MessageAddress>? Info { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the relationship class I have mentioned.

```
public class MessageAddress
{
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that I have created an `Address` class for two types of addresses using an enum. I have omitted the enum for brevity. Here's the code.

```
public class Address
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }  // Enum: PlainText, AddressCode
    public ICollection<MessageAddress> MessageAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that I have one one-to-many and two many-to-many relationships with the same type of owned classes. On `Add-Migration AddressUpgrade -Verbose`, I see this error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'MessageAddress' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.
```

I lost about 3 hours. What can I do to implement the requirement correctly?